# Make duration indicator of a HTML5 video counting up instead of down

Tags: jquery, html5-video

A timer underneath my HTML5 video is currently *counting down*.

`01:00` `00:59` `00:58` `00:57` and so on...

The jQuery rendering the timer:

```
// TIMER
    tv.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        var duration = document.getElementById('tv_time');
        var time = tv.duration - tv.currentTime;
        var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
        if (!isNaN(seconds) && !isNaN(minutes)) {
            duration.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + pad(seconds, 2);
        }
    }, false);
```

Instead of counting down, I wish the timer could be *counting up*.

`00:01` `00:02` `00:03` `00:04` and so on...

**Question:**

How could I best adjust the jQuery code, to have the counter count *up* instead of *down*?

**What I have tried:**

I tried fiddling with the multiplication and division:

```
var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
var seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
```

```
var minutes = Math.floor(time % 60);
var seconds = Math.floor(time / 60);
```

I tried to swap subtract for add:

```
var time = tv.duration - tv.currentTime;
```

```
var time = tv.duration + tv.currentTime;
```

I tried to say 'true' instead of 'false':

```
}, false);
```

```
}, true);
```

However, these examples just indicate that indeed I don't really know what I am doing here. I believe it's *time* for me to ask for guidance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change:

```
var time =  tv.currentTime - tv.duration;
```

To

```
     var time =  tv.currentTime;
```

Then it shows the current position => counting up

```
  tv.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
        var duration = document.getElementById('tv_time');
        var time =  tv.currentTime;
        var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
        var seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
        if (!isNaN(seconds) && !isNaN(minutes)) {
            duration.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + pad(seconds, 2);
        }
    }, false);
```